# Translation not loaded at start up in Angular app

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate, transloco

I encounter this problem on both ngx-translate and transloco in my Angular 15 app, so it might be a configuration issue.

When my app is loaded, in the `app.component.ts`, depending on if the user is logged in or not, he is redirected to the login component or the authenticated route I configured. Both are lazy loaded modules.
The translations on the page loaded are not showing (not even the translation key).
On the authenticated route, when I refresh, the translations are loaded only after a refresh or language change.
**This only happens when I try to use the default language though.**

Here is my configuration:

**transloco-root.module.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TranslocoHttpLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [TranslocoModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG,
      useValue: translocoConfig({
        availableLangs: ['en', 'fr'],
        defaultLang: 'en',
        // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: environment.production,
      }),
    },
    { provide: TRANSLOCO_LOADER, useClass: TranslocoHttpLoader },
  ],
})
export class TranslocoRootModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    CoreModule,
    ModulesModule,
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: !isDevMode(), // Restrict extension to log-only mode
      autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
      trace: false, //  If set to true, will include stack trace for every dispatched action, so you can see it in trace tab jumping directly to that part of code
      traceLimit: 75, // maximum stack trace frames to be stored (in case trace option was provided as true)
    }),
    TranslocoRootModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (authenticated) {
        ...
        this.router.navigate(['customers']);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
  }
```

**login.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, LoginRoutingModule, TranslocoModule],
  exports: [LoginComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

**login.component.html**

```
  <div id="sign-in-btn" class="sign-in">
    <button (click)="this.redirect()">{{ 'LOGIN.SIGN_IN' | transloco }}</button>
  </div>
```

I tried to force load the language and redirect after with `transloco.load('en').subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['login']);` but it never redirects. I took a look on the requests and the `en.json` file is never loaded.

I also tried to use the `APP_INITIALIZER` but didn't work.

Comment: Hi. Have the same issue. Transloco just not woring. Have you managed with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `TranslocoRootModule` instead of `TranslocoModule` in `LoginModule`